# unable to change timezone nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu

I want to set time zone of my Nodejs server running on ubuntu 20 to `Asia/Tehran` so:

First I changed ubuntu time zone using these command:

`timedatectl set-timezone Asia/Tehran` 
and `timedatectl` shows that I set it corretly:

> my@my-server:~$ timedatectl
> Local time: Thu 2023-08-31 11:48:33 +0330
> Universal time: Thu 2023-08-31 08:18:33 UTC
> RTC time: Thu 2023-08-31 08:18:34
> Time zone: Asia/Tehran (+0330, +0330)
> System clock synchronized: yes
> NTP service: active
> RTC in local TZ: no

Then I set this line in my Nodejs server.js:

`process.env.TZ = "Asia/Tehran";`

But time zone doesn't changed at all!

Server side `new Date()` returns `2023-08-31T08:30:32.447Z` although in Tehran it is `Thu Aug 31 2023 12:00:32 GMT+0330 (Iran Standard Time)`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just a hunch, but I think the environment variable `TZ` needs to be set before having to spin up the server. Probably try running `TZ='Asia/Tehran' node server.js` instead of setting the value of TZ inside `server.js`

Comment: Not working ... I just tested this ..

Comment: Ah, I see. You seem to be returning new Date() which would return ISO timestamp. If you want the date in a localized format, try `new Date().toLocaleString()` along with the TZ env set.

Comment: Ok, worked now, it would be accepted if you provide an answer

Answer (score 0):

You would need to probably set the environment variable before spinning up the server instance, so try running:

```bash
env TZ='Asia/Tehran' node server.js
```

This would set the timezone property correctly to Asia/Tehran. Now, running `new Date()` would return the ISO timestamp always, so to get the localized date/time format, you can use

```
new Date().toLocaleString()
```

which should return `8/31/2023, 2:15:30 PM` (depending on your set TZ).

To manipulate the formatting a bit more, I would prefer to use a date library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) or [day.js](https://day.js.org/) which provides advanced formatting abilities, including the ability to translate your result into a specific language (like Persian, for Tehran).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to make sure your Node.js server also uses the correct time zone:

1. **Restart the Node.js Application**: After changing the system time zone.
2. **Use `process.env.TZ`**: Node.js allows you to set the `TZ` environment variable to specify the desired time zone for your application. Make sure you set this environment variable when you start your Node.js server. You can do this in your command line or in your Node.js script.

   Command Line:

   ```bash
   TZ=Asia/Tehran node your_server.js
   ```

   Node.js Startup Script:

   ```js
   process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Tehran';
   // Rest of your server code
   ```
3. **Check Time Zone in Node.js**: You can also print out the current time zone within your Node.js application to ensure that it's correctly set

   ```js
   console.log('Current Time Zone:', process.env.TZ);
   ```